# Error with starting of MySQL using XAMPP on Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP on Windows 8.1. Apache and MySQL were previously working fine, but now MySQL suddenly stopped working.

I opened the error file and it shows the following:

```
InnoDB: Cannot open 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool' for reading: No such file or directory
```

I tried all methods by deleting the temporary files under `mysql/data` in the `xampp` folder. Then restarted the `xampp`. It did not work.
I even tried to change the default port for `mysql` from `3306` to `3307`, still no result.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling MySQL?

Comment: What version of MySQL? And did you change any config just before this happened

Comment: Changing the port MySQL listens on would have no effect on an error like this

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue today after installing Windows 10 update.  
 
It helped to re-installed XAMPP. Did the dirty work and now XAMPP is running. 
If you do try this make sure to back-up data folders (e.g htdocs) and export databases.